# Set event on calendar automatically (without popup) on Android

Tags: android, events, calendar

I can set the event on the calendar on my device by using this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

Now it displays a popup screen so the user can decide to set this event or not, so are there any way to make it automatically ? i mean i can set this event or cancel it by programing, not by waiting the touch from user.
Like the way i set the alarm clock, after i startActivity(intent), it was set automatically (not display a popup alarm clock for setup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can add event on calendar using this code

```
try
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    String[] timedevide = scheduletime.split(":");

    cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 
            Integer.parseInt(timedevide[0]), 
            Integer.parseInt(timedevide[1]), 00);

    Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(ctx) + "events");
    ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();

    // event insert
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("calendar_id", 1);
    values.put("title", title);
    values.put("allDay", 0);
    values.put("dtstart", cal.getTimeInMillis());
    values.put("dtend", cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    values.put("description", description);
    values.put("visibility", 0);
    values.put("hasAlarm", 1);
    Uri event = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
    addKeyToPreference(Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
    // reminder insert
    Uri REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(ctx) + "reminders");
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("event_id", Long.parseLong(event.getLastPathSegment()));
    values.put("method", 1);
    values.put("minutes", mTotalMinute);
    cr.insert(REMINDERS_URI, values);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}



private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity activity) {

    String calendarUriBase = null;
    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    try {
        managedCursor = activity.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        try {
            managedCursor = activity.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
        }
    }
    return calendarUriBase;
}
```

UPDATE

Managed query is deprecated Now

Android 4.0 (API Level 14) added a `CalendarContract` ContentProvider.

hope this helps

Comment: sorry, but i don't know where the variable "ctx" come from ?

Comment: that is your activity context....i am used this in a supporting class and i passed main activity context and assigned to ctx..u can add your context as 'yourActivityname.this'.getcontentResolver

Comment: What is getCalendarUriBase(Context) ??

Comment: If u adding this function in your activity then the context will be Activityname.this

Comment: Could you please provide the code for addKeyToPreference method?

Answer (score 1):

Good news and bad news.

The good news: Yes, this is possible using [`CalendarContract`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html).
The bad news: This api was introduced with ICS (Android 4.0) and wasn't available before that time.